# Openssl php not working

Tags: php, ssl, twitter, openssl

I am trying to build a twitter feed to search for relevant hashtags and display them in my mobile app. I found a package at http://mlemos.users.phpclasses.org/package/8109-PHP-Generate-RSS-feeds-from-timelines-and-searches.html that seems to do the job. However, opensll isnt loading. i get Error: it was not possible to open the API call URL: establishing SSL connections requires the OpenSSL extension enabled. Now, i have used open ssl on this machine before, and phpinfo says it is enabled. i have checked my php.ini file to make sure the line is uncommented, as well as check my path variable. No success. Google has turned up nothing helpful. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a twitAPI handler package